# Transparent glass with reflections in SceneKit

Tags: rendering, scenekit, pbr

Dear Scenekit Experts,

I'm trying to get a material resembling clear glass using PBR. It should be 99% transparent while also very reflective.

Here's the sample I'm using:

```
    lightingModel = .physicallyBased  
    metalness.contents = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)  
    diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)  
    roughness.contents = UIColor(white: CGFloat(0.03), alpha: 1.0)  

    transparencyMode = .dualLayer  
    isDoubleSided = true  
    transparency = 0.2
```

The problem is that the amount of reflections seem to be affected by the `transparency`:

1. `transparency = 0.01`: the reflections of the scenes environment map are barely visible anymore.
2. `transparency = 0.2`: I get some nice reflections, but unfortunately now my whole object is visible, i.e. it looks like a piece of tinted glass (depending on which color I set in `diffuse`).

How can I make it clear , i.e. see-through while still seeing the reflections ?

Comment: Have you tried to set an alpha value for the diffuse property instead of the transparency?

Comment: Unfortunately that has the same effect, the lower the alpha value, the smaller the reflection.
Somehow the shader program seems to multiply the whole contribution of the geometry by it's transparency/alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I think I figured it out myself now.
The solution was to set all alpha material values to `1.0` (`diffuse`, `transparency` etc) and then set the alpha in the fragment shader based on the amount of specular lighting.

Fragment Shader:

```
#pragma transparent
#pragma body
uniform sampler2D emissionTexture;

vec3 light = _lightingContribution.specular;
float alpha = 0.5 * min(1.0, 0.33 * light.r + 0.33 * light.g + 0.33 * light.b);
_output.color.rgb *= min(1.0, 1.5 * alpha);
_output.color.a = 0.75 * alpha;
```

Basically this shader has

- low alpha where there is no highlight
- high alpha where there is a specular highlight.